# Robocopy of folder redirection folders caused the volume to fill from ~1.5TB to the full 14T, as a result I cannot access the volume anymore

Tags: windows, iscsi, diskpart

I'd appreciate some help resolving this issue.  I was using robocopy to copy the contents from one iSCSI volume to another - moving folder redirection contents from the old to the new location.  There was about 600-700GB worth of data that needed to be migrated.

I'm not sure what happened but I noticed that no domain system could access the redirected folders.  I checked my TrueNAS target to see that the iSCSI share was at 100%.  I looked at the Win2k22 initiator which showed the iSCSI volume as offline.  I tried to get it online using disk management, but I had no luck.  So, I used "diskpart" to bring it online.  The drive properties show that 1.174T was used out of 14T.  I used "shrink querymax" to see how much space I could reclaim, which was around 12T.  However, when I used "shrink" I was told the disk was write-protected.  I cleared that attribute from the disk, but as soon as I do that, the volume goes down.  When I bring it back online, it's write-protected again, removing the write-protection causes the volume to go offline again, and so on and on and on - a cycle.

So, I'm a bit stuck.  As you can see, I can't clear the attribute without having the drive and volume go offline, but whenever I bring the drive and volume online, the attribute goes right back to read-only.

Any help will be greatly appreciated to help me solve this problem.

[image: Disk information]

[image: Space used]

[image: DISKPART]

Comment: Likely, your iSCSI target has messed up that volume. What kind of hardware does that TrueNAS run on? I'd simply format the volume and restore from backup.

Comment: I've been told that I messed up from the inception of the ZFS volume.  I should have limited the capacity to 80%, not the full 100%.

I am just wondering why things broke.  This was working perfectly for months.

The backup is another massive issue.  I tried using Windows Server Backup (WSB) to backup the 1.75TB, but it WSB will not back-up read-only volumes.